# All column names missing for a query result

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Column names are not displayed for a query.

For example, when I enter the query: `select * from V$tablespace;`

The system returns:

```
     0 SYSTEM                         YES NO  YES
     2 UNDOTBS1                       YES NO  YES
     1 SYSAUX                         YES NO  YES
     4 USERS                          YES NO  YES
     3 TEMP                           NO  NO  YES
     5 TABLE_SPACE1                   YES NO  YES
```

This happens with every other query I run.  Is there a fix?

Comment: Did you mean the tool PL/SQL Developer when you just wrote "PL/SQL" (because there is no PL/SQL at all in your question)

Comment: I'm novice enough with SQL Plus that this a little confusing. I'm using the command line. PL/SQL if that helps.

Comment: Where do you come up with "PL" in "PL/SQL"? What does that have to do with your question, or the way you run your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL*Plus, displaying or not displaying column names is a setting you control with the `SET` command. Note that all of this is only in the front-end (in SQL*Plus); Oracle returns the column names and the values, but you can instruct SQL*Plus to display or not to display the column names. They are called "HEADINGS" in SQL*Plus. To show them, type `SET HEADING ON`.

Demo:

```
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> set heading off

SQL> select * from dept;

        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> set heading on

SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```